# How can I sort numbers lexicographically?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, big-o

Here is the scenario.

I am given an array 'A' of integers. The size of the array is not fixed. The function that I am supposed to write may be called once with an array of just a few integers while another time, it might even contain thousands of integers. Additionally, each integer need not contain the same number of digits.

I am supposed to 'sort' the numbers in the array such that the resulting array has the integers ordered in a lexicographic manner (i.e they are sorted based on their string representations. Here "123" is the string representation of 123). Please note that the output should contain integers only, not their string equivalents.

**For example:** if the input is:

[ 12 | 2434 | 23 | 1 | 654 | 222 | 56 | 100000 ]

Then the output should be:

[ 1 | 100000 | 12 | 222 | 23 | 2434 | 56 | 654 ]

**My initial approach:** I converted each integer to its string format, then added zeros to its right to make all the integers contain the same number of digits (this was the messy step as it involved tracking etc making the solution very inefficient) and then did radix sort.
Finally, I removed the padded zeros, converted the strings back to their integers and put them in the resulting array. This was a very inefficient solution.

I've been led to believe that the solution doesn't need padding etc and there is a simple solution where you just have to process the numbers in some way (some bit processing?) to get the result.

What is the space-wise most efficient solution you can think of? Time-wise?

If you are giving code, I'd prefer Java or pseudo-code. But if that doesn't suit you, any such language should be fine.

Comment: Oh, the zero padding is required only if I do a radix sort (hope I am not misnaming it) because it is easier that way. In it I just examine a particular position of each integer during an iteration. If I do a simple 'strcmp' I guess, that won't be required.

Comment: Actually, if you're doing a radix sort from s[0], then you don't need to pad.

Comment: Ah.. true, now why did I do that? :D Hope I ain't forgetting something.

Comment: Hmm.... @everyone: so you all feel there is really no "trick" that you can do to get the desired output without converting them to strings. It felt stupid to think yes, but someone told me think in terms of bits and you get the answer. I've been racking my brains ever since :)

Comment: There may very well be a trick. But the amount of effort you will expend to get it right is probably not going to be worth it. If your goal is to just get a decently performing solution. Use a comparator function. If you want the best possible performance, then you may need to go for the "trick"

Comment: Depends on your goal, I suppose. If this is an interview question/puzzle for fun, then sure, it might be interesting to try to figure out. If this is a real problem you need solved, or a HW assignment, I'd just say do it the straight forward way...

Comment: RE the trick: it seems unlikely that something complicated with bits will give you useful information about digits... It's most likely that writing a comparison using /10 and %10 in a loop...

Answer (score 10):

Executable pseudo-code (aka Python): `thenumbers.sort(key=str)`. Yeah, I know that using Python is kind of like cheating -- it's just **too** powerful;-). But seriously, this also means: if you can sort an array of strings lexicographically, as Python's sort intrinsically can, then just make the "key string" out of each number and sort that auxiliary array (you can then reconstruct the desired numbers array by a str->int transformation, or by doing the sort on the indices via indirection, etc etc); this is known as DSU (Decorate, Sort, Undecorate) and it's what the `key=` argument to Python's sort implements.

In more detail (pseudocode):

1. allocate an array of char** `aux` as long as the `numbers` array
2. for i from 0 to `length of numbers-1`, `aux[i]=stringify(numbers[i])`
3. allocate an array of int `indices` of the same length
4. for i from 0 to `length of numbers-1`, `indices[i]=i`
5. sort `indices`, using as `cmp(i,j)` `strcmp(aux[i],aux[j])`
6. allocate an array of int `results` of the same length
7. for i from 0 to `length of numbers-1`, `results[i]=numbers[indices[i]]`
8. memcpy `results` over `numbers`
9. free every `aux[i]`, and also `aux`, `indices`, `results`

Comment: That's cool. However, I am in search of an algorithm, than a way to do it in a particular language. :)

Comment: ...and aren't the steps 1 to 9 I list under "in more detail" enough of "an algorithm" for you...?

Comment: When I first left the comment, I suppose only the first two lines were there. :) You added the pseudocode algorithm later, didn't you? :) Now, those steps are helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Since you mentioned Java is the actual language in question:

You don't need to convert to and from strings.  Instead, define your own comparator and use that in the sort.

Specifically:

```
Comparator<Integer> lexCompare = new Comparator<Integer>(){
   int compareTo( Integer x, Integer y ) {
      return x.toString().compareTo( y.toString() );
   }
};
```

Then you can sort the array like this:

```
int[] array = /* whatever */;
Arrays.sort( array, lexCompare );
```

(Note: The `int`/`Integer` mismatch works automatically through auto-boxing)

Answer (score 3):

I'd just turn them into strings, and then sort then sort using strcmp, which does lex comparisons.

Alternatively you can write a "lexcmp" function that compares two numbers using % 10 and /10 but that's basically the same thing as calling atoi many times, so not a good idea.

Comment: Do you mean convert the whole array into an array of strings, or just do the conversion when the comparison is made?

Comment: you can do either, but I convert the whole array so you only do it once. Otherwise, you have to convert each number many (log n) times which is expensive...

Comment: Converting log n times is not expensive if you are reading your data from CPU cache or registers (if you are on a register rich architecture). Perhaps you are right, but I've run into situtations where doing more work from data in the cache beats preprocessing the array.

Answer (score 3):

The actual sorting can be done by any algorithm you like. The key to this problem is finding the comparison function that will properly identify which numbers should be "less than" others, according to this scheme:

```
bool isLessThan(int a, int b)
{
    string aString = ToString(a);
    string bString = ToString(b);

    int charCount = min(aString.length(), bString.length())
    for (charIndex = 0; charIndex < charCount; charIndex++)
    {
        if (aString[charIndex] < bString[charIndex]) { return TRUE; }
    }

    // if the numbers are of different lengths, but identical
    // for the common digits (e.g. 123 and 12345)
    // the shorter string is considered "less"
    return (aString.length() < bString.length());
}
```

Comment: That was a neat comparison, thanks. This, in combination with the batch conversion to strings, then sorting, should probably be a best solution if nothing else works out.

Comment: Ah, ok.. I'll decide batch conversion or not after all the answers are in.

Comment: Batch string conversion should improve things substantially. I don't know of a sorting function that performs better than O(n), which means that the conversion to a string will have to happen for each node more than once. My comparison function would even do each one twice! Given the number of divisions required to convert an integer to a string, I'd be surprised if the string conversion wasn't your bottleneck.

Answer (score 2):

My temptation would be to say that the int to string conversion would happen in the comparitor code rather than in bulk. Although this may be more elegant from a code-perspective I'd have to say that the execution effort would be greater as each number may be  compared several times.

I'd be inclined to create a new array containing both the int and string representation (not sure that you need to pad the string versions for the string comparison to produce the order you've given), sort that on the string and then copy the int values back to the original array.

I can't think of a smart mathematically way of sorting this as by your own statement you want to sort lexicographically so you need to transform the numbers to strings to do that.

Answer (score 2):

You definitely don't need to pad the result. It will not change the order of the lexicographical compare, it will be more error prone, and it will just waste CPU cycles. The most "space-wise" efficient method would be to convert the numbers to strings when they are compared. That way, you would not need to allocate an additional array, the numbers would be compared in place.

You can get a reasonably good implementation quickly by just converting them to strings as needed. Stringifying a number isn't particularly expensive and, since you are only dealing with two strings at a time, it is quite likely that they will remain in the CPU cache at all times. So the comparisons will be much faster than the case where you convert the entire array to strings since they will not need to be loaded from main memory into the cache. People tend to forget that a CPU has a cache and that algorithms which do a lot of their work in a small local area of memory will benefit greatly from the much faster cache access. On some architectures, the cache is so much faster than the memory that you can do hundreds of operations on your data in the time it would have taken you to load it from main memory. So doing more work in the comparison function could actually be significantly faster than pre-processing the array. Especially if you have a large array.

Try doing the string serialization and comparison in a comparator function and benchmark that. I think it will be a pretty good solution. Example java-ish pseudo-code:

```
public static int compare(Number numA, Number numB) {
    return numA.toString().compare(numB.toString());
}
```

I think that any fancy bit wise comparisons you could do would have to be approximately equivalent to the work involved in converting the numbers to strings. So you probably wouldn't get significant benefit. You can't just do a direct bit for bit comparison, that would give you a different order than lexicographical sort. You'll need to be able to figure out each digit for the number anyway, so it is most straightforward to just make them strings. There may be some slick trick, but every avenue I can think of off the top of my head is tricky, error-prone, and much more work than it is worth.

Comment: As an afterthought. This may also depend greatly on the language you are using. In C this is probably true. In more dynamic languages, there may be enough overhead in calling the comparison function to overwhelm the cache benefit.

Answer (score 1):

Pseudocode:

```
sub sort_numbers_lexicographically (array) {
    for 0 <= i < array.length:
        array[i] = munge(array[i]);
    sort(array);  // using usual numeric comparisons
    for 0 <= i < array.length:
        array[i] = unmunge(array[i]);
}
```

So, what are `munge` and `unmunge`?

`munge` is different depending on the integer size.  For example:

```
sub munge (4-bit-unsigned-integer n) {
    switch (n):
        case 0:  return 0
        case 1:  return 1
        case 2:  return 8
        case 3:  return 9
        case 4:  return 10
        case 5:  return 11
        case 6:  return 12
        case 7:  return 13
        case 8:  return 14
        case 9:  return 15
        case 10:  return 2
        case 11:  return 3
        case 12:  return 4
        case 13:  return 5
        case 14:  return 6
        case 15:  return 7
}
```

Esentially what munge is doing is saying what order 4 bit integers come in when sorted lexigraphically.  I'm sure you can see that there is a pattern here --- I didn't have to use a switch --- and that you can write a version of `munge` that handles 32 bit integers reasonably easily.  Think about how you would write versions of `munge` for 5, 6, and 7 bit integers if you can't immediately see the pattern.

`unmunge` is the inverse of `munge`.

So you can avoid converting anything to a string --- you don't need any extra memory.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to try a better preprocess-sort-postprocess, then note that an int is at most 10 decimal digits (ignoring signed-ness for the time being).

So the binary-coded-decimal data for it fits in 64 bits. Map digit 0->1, 1->2 etc, and use 0 as a NUL terminator (to ensure that "1" comes out less than "10"). Shift each digit in turn, starting with the smallest, into the top of a long. Sort the longs, which will come out in lexicographical order for the original ints. Then convert back by shifting digits one at a time back out of the top of each long:

```
uint64_t munge(uint32_t i) {
    uint64_t acc = 0;
    while (i > 0) {
        acc = acc >> 4;
        uint64_t digit = (i % 10) + 1;
        acc += (digit << 60);
        i /= 10;
    }
    return acc;
}

uint32_t demunge(uint64_t l) {
    uint32_t acc = 0;
    while (l > 0) {
        acc *= 10;
        uint32_t digit = (l >> 60) - 1;
        acc += digit;
        l << 4;
    }
}
```

Or something like that. Since Java doesn't have unsigned ints, you'd have to modify it a little. It uses a lot of working memory (twice the size of the input), but that's still less than your initial approach. It might be faster than converting to strings on the fly in the comparator, but it uses more peak memory. Depending on the GC, it might churn its way through less memory total, though, and require less collection.

Answer (score 1):

If all the numbers are less than 1E+18, you could cast each number to UINT64, multiply by ten and add one, and then multiply by ten until they are at least 1E+19.  Then sort those.  To get back the original numbers, divide each number by ten until the last digit is non-zero (it should be one) and then divide by ten once more.

Answer (score 1):

The question doesn't indicate how to treat negative integers in the lexicographic collating order.  The string-based methods presented earlier typically will sort negative values to the front; eg, { -123, -345, 0, 234, 78 } would be left in that order.  But if the minus signs were supposed to be ignored, the output order should be { 0, -123, 234, -345, 78 }.  One could adapt a string-based method to produce that order by somewhat-cumbersome additional tests.

It may be simpler, in both theory and code, to use a comparator that compares fractional parts of common logarithms of two integers.  That is, it will compare the mantissas of base 10 logarithms of two numbers.  A logarithm-based comparator will run faster or slower than a string-based comparator, depending on a CPU's floating-point performance specs and on quality of implementations.

The java code shown at the end of this answer includes two logarithm-based comparators:  `alogCompare` and `slogCompare`.  The former ignores signs, so would produce { 0, -123, 234, -345, 78 } from { -123, -345, 0, 234, 78 }.

The number-groups shown next are the output produced by the  java program.

The  “dar rand” section shows a random-data array `dar` as generated.  It reads across and then down, 5 elements per line.  Note, arrays `sar`, `lara`, and `lars` initially are unsorted copies of `dar`.

The “dar sort” section is `dar` after sorting via `Arrays.sort(dar);`.

The “sar lex” section shows array `sar` after sorting with `Arrays.sort(sar,lexCompare);`, where `lexCompare` is similar to the `Comparator` shown in Jason Cohen's answer.

The “lar s log” section shows array `lars` after sorting by `Arrays.sort(lars,slogCompare);`, illustrating a logarithm-based method that gives the same order as do `lexCompare` and other string-based methods.

The “lar a log” section shows array `lara` after sorting by `Arrays.sort(lara,alogCompare);`, illustrating a logarithm-based method that ignores minus signs.

```
dar rand    -335768    115776     -9576    185484     81528
dar rand      79300         0      3128      4095    -69377
dar rand     -67584      9900    -50568   -162792     70992

dar sort    -335768   -162792    -69377    -67584    -50568
dar sort      -9576         0      3128      4095      9900
dar sort      70992     79300     81528    115776    185484

 sar lex    -162792   -335768    -50568    -67584    -69377
 sar lex      -9576         0    115776    185484      3128
 sar lex       4095     70992     79300     81528      9900

lar s log    -162792   -335768    -50568    -67584    -69377
lar s log      -9576         0    115776    185484      3128
lar s log       4095     70992     79300     81528      9900

lar a log          0    115776   -162792    185484      3128
lar a log    -335768      4095    -50568    -67584    -69377
lar a log      70992     79300     81528     -9576      9900
```

Java code is shown below.

```
// Code for "How can I sort numbers lexicographically?" - jw - 2 Jul 2014
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.lang.Math;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class lex882954 {
// Comparator from Jason Cohen's answer
    public static Comparator<Integer> lexCompare = new Comparator<Integer>(){
        public int compare( Integer x, Integer y ) {
            return x.toString().compareTo( y.toString() );
        }
    };
// Comparator that uses "abs." logarithms of numbers instead of strings
    public static Comparator<Integer> alogCompare = new Comparator<Integer>(){
        public int compare( Integer x, Integer y ) {
            Double xl = (x==0)? 0 : Math.log10(Math.abs(x));
            Double yl = (y==0)? 0 : Math.log10(Math.abs(y));
            Double xf=xl-xl.intValue();
            return xf.compareTo(yl-yl.intValue());
        }
    };
// Comparator that uses "signed" logarithms of numbers instead of strings
    public static Comparator<Integer> slogCompare = new Comparator<Integer>(){
        public int compare( Integer x, Integer y ) {
            Double xl = (x==0)? 0 : Math.log10(Math.abs(x));
            Double yl = (y==0)? 0 : Math.log10(Math.abs(y));
            Double xf=xl-xl.intValue()+Integer.signum(x);
            return xf.compareTo(yl-yl.intValue()+Integer.signum(y));
        }
    };
// Print array before or after sorting
    public static void printArr(Integer[] ar, int asize, String aname) {
        int j;
        for(j=0; j < asize; ++j) {
            if (j%5==0)
                System.out.printf("%n%8s ", aname);
            System.out.printf(" %9d", ar[j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
// Main Program -- to test comparators
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int j, dasize=15, hir=99;
        Random rnd = new Random(12345);
        Integer[] dar = new Integer[dasize];
        Integer[] sar = new Integer[dasize];
        Integer[] lara = new Integer[dasize];
        Integer[] lars = new Integer[dasize];

        for(j=0; j < dasize; ++j) {
            lara[j] = lars[j] = sar[j] = dar[j] = rnd.nextInt(hir) * 
                rnd.nextInt(hir) * (rnd.nextInt(hir)-44);
        }
        printArr(dar, dasize, "dar rand");
        Arrays.sort(dar);
        printArr(dar, dasize, "dar sort");
        Arrays.sort(sar, lexCompare);
        printArr(sar, dasize, "sar lex");
        Arrays.sort(lars, slogCompare);
        printArr(lars, dasize, "lar s log");
        Arrays.sort(lara, alogCompare);
        printArr(lara, dasize, "lar a log");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're going for space-wise efficiency, I'd try just doing the work in the comparison function of the sort

```
int compare(int a, int b) {
   // convert a to string
   // convert b to string
   // return -1 if a < b, 0 if they are equal, 1 if a > b
}
```

If it's too slow (it's slower than preprocessing, for sure), keep track of the conversions somewhere so that the comparison function doesn't keep having to do them.

Answer (score 0):

Possible optimization: Instead of this:

> I converted each integer to its string format, then added zeros to its right to make all the integers contain the same number of digits

you can multiply each number by (10^N - log10(number)), N being a number larger than log10 of any of your numbers.

Comment: Although this would have 1 comparing equal to 100, for example (as does the original).

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @x = ( 12, 2434, 23, 1, 654, 222, 56, 100000 );

print $_, "\n" for sort @x;

__END__
```

Some timings ... First, with empty @x:

```
C:\Temp> timethis s-empty
TimeThis :  Elapsed Time :  00:00:00.188
```

Now, with 10,000 randomly generated elements:

```
TimeThis :  Elapsed Time :  00:00:00.219
```

This includes the time taken to generate the 10,000 elements but not the time to output them to the console. The output adds about a second.

So, save some programmer time ;-)

Answer (score 0):

One really hacky method (using C) would be:

- generate a new array of all the values converted to floats
- do a sort using the mantissa (significand) bits for the comparison

In Java (from [here](http://www.daniweb.com/forums/thread21094.html#)):

```
long bits = Double.doubleToLongBits(5894.349580349);

boolean negative = (bits & 0x8000000000000000L) != 0; 
long exponent = bits & 0x7ff0000000000000L >> 52;
long mantissa = bits & 0x000fffffffffffffL;
```

so you would sort on the long `mantissa` here.

Comment: That sorts them lexicographically in base 2 (assuming no loss of precision). Questioner wants them sorted lexicographically in base 10. So what you said, but using BigDecimal, could be a winner. Probably not (much) faster than String, though.