# Push method for future past events

Tags: javascript, firebase

I want to set data with timestamp priority in the past or future, but not at the current date. And then be able to make queries with endAt and StartAt for specific dates (365 days)

The push method is great to set unique IDs for data and manage the order. Is there any method to generate a "unique PushId" like push() method for timestamp in past or future?

Comment: Have you looked at the docs for [ordered data](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-ordered-data) and priorities? What did you try? What didn't work?

Comment: I know I can set custom timestamps(past/future) for each data and then set priorities with every timestamp ([like this](https://examples-sql-queries.firebaseio.com/messages)). But I was wondering if I can set  keys to order the data and also make a unique id like push() method does. If the right way is only to set custom timestamps, is there any way to get a timestamp from the unique ID set by push() method? Sorry, maybe I'm exaggerating to reuse data stored or avoid writing repetitive data. But still I have no experience in scale denormalizing data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attempt to create unique ids similar to what push does, but this seems like a lot of work for little gain when there are built in tools in Firebase to order data. The simplest answer is to set a priority on each record using the server timestamp.

```
ref.push({ ...data..., ".priority": Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP });
```

To set one in the future or past, specify the timestamp manually.

```
ref.push({ ...data..., ".priority": timeInTheFuture });
```

[.info/serverTimeOffset](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/offline-capabilities.html#section-latency) may also be helpful here for handling latency.

To create push ids, you would do something similar to the following:

1. Get the current timestamp and pad it to a fixed length (i.e. 16 characters)
2. Append a random series of digits, such as a random number or hash, also padded to a fixed length
3. Your entry will now look something like this:  `000128198239:KHFDBWYBEFIWFE`
4. You now have a lexicographically sortable id based on a timestamp, which is unique

Here's a helpful [discussion on sorting numbers lexicographically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/882954/how-can-i-sort-numbers-lexicographically/883036#883036)