# Firebase orderByKey() inconsistent ordering of keys

Tags: javascript, firebase, angularfire

There are some business requirements I have to align to and my keys are partly created by Firebase web api (eg -JzuZoAtZ9fKY9z3GbEU) partly manually (eg 304810429574385)

Firebase version I use: `"version": "2.2.7"`

I am using `orderByKey()` query to sort items and as [documentation points out](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-ordered-data):

> 1. Children with a key that can be parsed as a 32-bit integer come first, sorted in ascending order.
> 2. Children with a string value as their key come next, sorted lexicographically in ascending order.

Could anyone give me some insight why firebase generated keys are not treated like normal strings and their location seems to be unpredictable as if they are numbers?

Examples of sorted keys I have for two separate endpoints:

```
// case no 1
-JzLOQGFCw6ZwHnQZPFR
-JzuZoAtZ9fKY9z3GbEU
163467300371184
222032364474376
386146869432

// case no 2
222441849
225215973
225484186
-JzpekQUr7jRDHo5qk3D
```

Links to Firebase data cases [FIRST](https://bugsfire.firebaseio.com/ordering/case1.json?orderBy=%22$key%22)and [SECOND](https://bugsfire.firebaseio.com/ordering/case2.json?orderBy=%22$key%22)

[JSfiddle `orderByKey()` usage.](http://jsfiddle.net/ivarprudnikov/7ds8nar1/)

The previous output was printed using:

```
var keys = [];
fireRef.orderByKey().on('child_added',function(snap){
    keys.push(snap.key());
});
```

It is the same when getting data via REST api, when ordering with `orderBy="$key"`:

```
GET https://my_app.firebaseio.com/one/two/three.json?orderBy="$key"&auth=superSecret
```

The same if using angularfire:

```
$scope.items = $firebaseArray(fireRef.orderByKey());
```

Comment: It will be difficult to help without a sample of your data in a database. If you set up a separate Firebase database for it, you won't have to share your secret and I can have a look.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I've added links to question that point to two described data cases and to jsfiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The numbers in your case 1 are bigger than [what fits in a 32 bit integer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2147483647#In_computing): `2147483647`

It's more obvious what happens if you put the two lists together:

```
222441849
225215973
225484186
-JzLOQGFCw6ZwHnQZPFR
-JzuZoAtZ9fKY9z3GbEU
163467300371184
222032364474376
386146869432
```

The numbers before the push ids (the keys starting with `-J`) are ordered by their numeric values. The numbers after the push ids don't fit in a 32 bit integer and thus (as described in the doc you quote) are [ordered by their lexicographic value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/882954/how-can-i-sort-numbers-lexicographically).