# Java custom sort of Integer objects in ArrayList<Integer>

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, integer

I have an ArrayList containing the following numbers:

```
[6902, 6903, 6904, 790, 10902, 10903, 10904, 1190, 7901, 7902, 7903, 7904, 8904
, 990, 9901, 9902, 890, 8901, 8902, 8903, 6503, 6504, 690, 6901, 12904, 1310, 1
3101, 13102, 13103, 13104, 9903, 9904, 1090, 10901, 1290, 12901, 12902, 12903, 
11901, 11902, 11903, 11904, 5903, 5904, 590, 5901, 5902, 650, 6501, 6502]
```

Now the natural ordering with `Collections.sort` would be 590, 650, 690 and so on. 
But I need the ordering to be 590, 5901, 5902, 5903, 5904, 650, 6501, 6502, 6503...

Is there an elegant to way to do this or do I have to `iterate` over the `ArrayList` and get my desired sorting with many many `if / elseifs`?

Comment: What's your sort logic?

Comment: It seems you want *lexicographical* order. Convert items to `String` sort the `ArrayList` finally get back to `int`

Comment: there is always a way. convert to String, sort alphabetically, convert to Integer again

Comment: Please add an [MCVE]

Comment: There are already some related questions: [Sorting an array of int in lexicographic order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/882954/how-can-i-sort-numbers-lexicographically) and [How can I sort numbers lexicographically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/882954/how-can-i-sort-numbers-lexicographically).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I think you would like the values to be sorted lexicographically all you have to do is use comparator that turns both the items into strings.

```
list.sort(Comparator.comparing(Object::toString));
System.out.println(list);
```

> [1, 1090, 10901, 10902, 10903, 10904, 1190, 11901, 11902, 11903, 11904, 1290, 12901, 12902, 12903, 12904, 1310, 13102, 13103, 13104, 3101, 590, 5901, 5902, 5903, 5904, 650, 6501, 6502, 6503, 6504, 690, 6901, 6902, 6903, 6904, 790, 7901, 7902, 7903, 7904, 890, 8901, 8902, 8903, 8904, 990, 9901, 9902, 9903, 9904]

Answer (score 3):

Use [Collections.sort(List, Comparator)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,java.util.Comparator)) and provide your own comparator that gives your desired order.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Comparator interface to achieve this.
Make a class implementing Comparator interface

```
class compareInt implements Comparator<Integer>{

    public int compare(Integer a, Integer b)// Override This method as your need
        {
           return 0; //should -1,0 or 1 to sort Integers
        }
    }
```

Use This link to know more about Comparator method: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/comparator-interface-java/